# Connecting a rails application with sunspot to a tomcat/solr server with authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, solr, production-environment, sunspot-rails

Okay, so I have a separate server with solr and this connects perfectly fine with the app. Using the usual sunspot.yml we have something like:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: domain
    port: 8080
    log_level: WARNING
    path: path/to/data
```

The problem is I wanted to authorization to my tomcat app. It seems that as long as you know the domain and port you could just go and visit solr/admin. So in my tomcat web.xml I added:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name> 
        Solr authenticated application
      </web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
   <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>REALM</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <description>ROLE NAME</description>
    <role-name>role</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

This would require anyone visiting solr/admin a username and password before being granted access. The problem is how do I tell my rails app about this? After doing this and I get an expected "Unauthorized" response when my rails app tries to access the solr server. I know it would probably go into the sunspot.yml file but what do I have to add?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure that the Sunspot configuration supports a Basic Auth username and password via the YAML. Those options are all concatenated together to be assigned to `Sunspot.config.solr.url` and later given to RSolr. That's a simple oversight — a pull request at https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot would be welcome to fix that.

You will have better luck either assigning `Sunspot.config.solr.url` directly in an initializer, or by specifying the URL via an environment variable. Sunspot supports the `SOLR_URL` and `WEBSOLR_URL` environment variables, and in doing so should preserve a Basic Auth username and password.

To test this in your development environment:

```
rake sunspot:reindex SOLR_URL=http://admin:foobar@localhost:8983/solr
rails server SOLR_URL=http://admin:foobar@localhost:8983/solr
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/justinko/sunspot-rails-http-basic-auth

gem install this. its HTTP Basic Authentication support for sunspot_rails. You can then put the username and password in the sunspot.yml that is generated.

Comment: This looks promising. I do not have the time yet to try this out but will definitely consider this when I have some time.